# CiviContribute Pages have differing wrong titles in <head>

Tags: civicontribute, drupal

We are having a strange issue where different titles for our CiviContribute pages show up in the `<head> <title>` section, so the title shows up wrong in the tab, bookmark, etc. Sometimes it will be the name of one of our CiviContribute pages, and sometimes another. Today, they all say "Donate" for example, which is what one of our CiviContribute pages should be called. But other users will report that the title is "Subscribe" on all the pages, which is the example name of another of our CiviContribute pages.

We are using a really old version and are currently working on updating it now but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a simple explanation before putting it on hold for the upgrade.

Any ideas?

Drupal 7.50, CiviCRM 4.3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the most recent version of CiviCRM (4.7.15) solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by caching solutions, for instance if you use Drupal with GlobalRedirect or Boost module？